# How to add unique constraint that depends of the foreign key values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one table with contains foreign key "columnA" column and one more column "columnB". I want to prevent adding same values in "columnB" but only for same value in "columnA"...

```
columnA  columnB 
 1        'a'       
 1        'a' - this is not allowed  
 2        'a' - this is allowed
```

From my perspective only way to do that is by using trigger, but i suppose that there is a better, more elegant way to make this constraint. Do you know best way to make this logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Unique constraint would work.

```
alter table TableName add constraint UQ_consrtaint unique(columnA, columnB);
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to create a primary key like this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [A] TINYINT
   ,[B] CHAR
   ,PRIMARY KEY([A], [B])
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([A], [B])
VALUES (1, 'a'); -- ok

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([A], [B])
VALUES (2, 'a'); -- ok

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([A], [B])
VALUES (1, 'a'); -- error
```

It will give you the following error:

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 14 Violation of PRIMARY KEY
>   constraint 'PK__#B1CFBEC__D86D1834E734E52B'. Cannot insert duplicate
>   key in object 'dbo.@DataSource'. The duplicate key value is (1, a).

in the case above.

Or unique constrain on the two columns:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [A] TINYINT
   ,[B] CHAR
   ,UNIQUE ([A], [B])
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD UNIQUE uniqueconstraintname(columnA, columnB);
```